# No Such Methods Error in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, nosuchmethoderror

I'm writing a jsp page called Diet which uses a java file called DietHelper. I have figured out the problem happens in the line when I declare String variable and assign it with the return method from java file, while is line sting b = todayDiet.getBreakfastList().

In the DietHelper.java.

```
public class DietHelper
  {
                  public boolean diet;
                    public String mood; 

   public DietHelper(boolean diet, String mood)
   {
    this.diet = diet;
    this.mood = mood;
}


  public int roll()
{
    return randomGenerator.nextInt(1)+0;
}

  public String getBreakfastList()
{   

    if(this.diet == true && this.mood.equals("high"))
    {
       breakfast[0] = "bread";
       breakfast[1] = "chili";
    }
     this.breakfastfood = breakfast[roll()];

    return String.format("Your breakfast may choose %s", this.breakfastfood);
}
```

In the Diet.jsp,

```
 {
        DietHelper todayDiet = new DietHelper(true, "sweet");


String b = todayDiet.getBreakfastList();
out.print(b +"<br/>");
}
```

when I run it on the html page, it's saying

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP.page [/Diet.jsp] at line [52]: String b = todayDiet.getBreakfastList();
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:Diet.DietHelper.getBreakfastList()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Did you import the `DietHelper` class?

Comment: It seems that you have imported that class but ... are you sure that you have deployed the last version correctly in your server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your jsp execute java code, you must use JSP scriptlet tag.
So in your jsp, you should add JSP scriptlet tag like this with imported class files which related with the methods.

```
<%@ page import="package.DietHelper" %>
<% { 
        DietHelper todayDiet = new DietHelper(true, "sweet");   
String b = todayDiet.getBreakfastList();
out.print(b +"<br/>");
} %>
```

Lastly, build and clean your project and also clean and restart your server.

Comment: Then, I think u just need import the related class files with the methods you want if assume ur logic is correct.